# Can you explain this overload resolution behavior?

Tags: c++

This code snippet will not compile using VS2013 or ICC 16:

```
class C2;

class C1
{
public:
  float x, y;

  template<typename T>
  C1 (T x, T y) : x(static_cast<float>(x)), y(static_cast<float>(y)) {};
  C1 (const C2 &a, int i) : x(0), y(0) {};
};

void main()
{
    C1 p(1.5, 2);
}
```

because no instance of `C1` constructor matches the argument list `(double, int)`, but when I replace `C2` with `PolyLine` it does compile and `1.5` is somehow cast to `PolyLine`. I test it inside a large project with many dependencies, so I can fit only a fragment of the header here:

```
class PolyLine 
{
protected:
    enum {INIT_LENGTH = 16};

public:
  typedef float (PolyLine::*Fit)(Point2D&, Point2D&, const int, const int, const float) const;

    vector<float> x;  ///< Vector with X axis coordinates of polyline nodes.
    vector<float> y;  ///< Vector with Y axis coordinates of polyline nodes.

    PolyLine (int initLength = INIT_LENGTH);
    PolyLine (const PolyLine &poly, int firstNode = -1, int lastNode = -1);
    PolyLine (const PolyLine &poly, const float MAX_ERROR, vector<int> *nodeMap = 0);
    PolyLine (ifstream* input);
  PolyLine (string fileName)  {loadTxt (fileName);};
    PolyLine (const float SAMPLING_RESOLUTION, PolyLine &poly);
    PolyLine (const vector<float> &v, float step = 1.0);
    PolyLine (const vector<int> &v, float step = 1.0);
    PolyLine (const deque<float> &x, const deque<float> &y) : x(x.begin(), x.end()), y(y.begin(), y.end()) {};
```

What are the circumstances when `PolyLine` can be cast to `double`?

**EDIT**

After reading the first answers, I reduced this example to:

```
class PolyLine 
{
public:
  PolyLine(int i = 7) {};
};
```

Marking `PolyLine` constructor `explicit` produces desired effect.

Comment: @Barry Yes, I wanted it _not to compile_. This cast was a total surprise to me and I don't want the `double` to be cast to `PolyLine` - it makes no sense. I marked the `PolyLine(int)` constructor explicit to prevent it from happening as suggested by @Dani. My question was about _explaining_ this behaviour, which you did very well, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to call `C1::C1(double, int)`. There are two names that are found:

```
template <typename T> C1::C1(T, T);
C1::C1(const C2&, int);
```

The first one is not viable - your arguments have different types so you can't call a template on a single type.

So that leaves the second one. The second one is viable if you can construct a `C2` from a `double`. In your initial example, `C2` is incomplete, so you can't construct it from *anything*, hence it can't compile. However, for `PolyLine` we do have this constructor:

```
PolyLine (int );
```

As part of the conversion sequence, we are allowed to do zero or one standard conversion and zero or one user-defined conversion. `double --> int` is an allowed standard conversion and `int --> PolyLine` is an allowed user-defined conversion.

As such, the `C1::C1(const PolyLine&, int)` is a viable constructor. Since it's the only viable constructor, that makes it trivially the best viable constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the implicit `double` to `Polyline` you can mark the constructor explicit:

```
explicit PolyLine (int initLength = INIT_LENGTH);
```